# declaring scopes from an array in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, scopes

I have an array of symbols, and I'd like to declare a scope in an ActiveRecord model for each one.

The following does not work:

```
@@animal_types = [:horse, :cat, :dog]
@@animal_types.each do |a|
    scope a, :conditions => "animal_type = '#{a.to_s}'"
end
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Update:** I was testing this incorrectly, this does in fact work

Comment: That seems to work for me in Rails 3.2. What version are you on?

Comment: this is on rails 3.0.20

Comment: Works for me in rail 3.0.20 as well. Do you get an error or any output on console, like when you run 'YourModel.horse.to_sql`?

Comment: sorry, I was testing this incorrectly - it does work for me.  thanks for your help

Comment: Just a comment: Avoid using @@variables, you can use @foo as well in context of a class.

Assume the following: `class Foo;@@bar = :a;end` and `class Bar < Foo;@@bar = :b;end;` What's the value of `@@bar` within of Foo?

Surprisingly, it is `:b`, `@@variables` are shared across "Subclasses"